# Alias with regex

Tags: email, postfix, alias

I want to forward an email from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` using `/etc/aliases`

The incoming email has the following syntax: `mail+somerandomstring@domain1.com` and should be forwarded to `mail+somerandomstring@domain2.com`

The problem is that the part behind the `+` (recipient_delimiter) is random but still has to be forwarded.

I looked into regex for the aliases but it seems this only works for the left hand side.

Is there any way I can achieve the forwarding using `/etc/aliases` or another easy solution?

Comment: You should be able to do it with virtual, and a regex table /^mail\+(.*)@domain1.com/  mail+${1}@domain2.com, if my regex sysntax is OK (not sure if the plus needs to be escaped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using regex in the virtual alias table in postfix' `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

and then

```
/^mail+([^@]*)@domain1.com/ mail+$(1)@domain2.com
```

Comment: Hello from seven years in the future! How did this work without escaping the `+` sign in the regex? Shouldn't it be `/^mail\+([^@]*)@domain1.com/`? I'm just curious, because it looks like your version is supposed to match e.g. _maillllllsomething@domain1.com_?